# Resort the rank after updating it

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank

There is a student table with their scores:

```
studentid    studentscore    rank
----------------------------------
1             77              6
2             80              4
3             90              2
4             94              1
5             78              5
6             88              3
```

However, the score of id 1 and 5 are wrong, id 1 should be 78 and id 5 should be 77.

I update their scores, but how to resort their ranks?

Comment: You could delete the `rank` column and buils it every time in your select on-the-fly.

Comment: There's much data in the table actually, is there a way to use select only? And what if I must update more than 2 scores?

Comment: @user618520 -  "And what if I must update more than 2 scores?" The UPDATE statements and SELECT statement provided here in the answers below will do the job selecting and updating correctly even if you change 100 studentscore  or one studentscore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Mureinik points out, you can just generate rank on the fly. However if you need to store it (possibly for performance reasons) you can update the table using a CTE with the new ranks:

```
WITH ranks AS (
  SELECT studentid, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY studentscore DESC) AS [rank]
  FROM students
)
UPDATE s
SET s.[rank] = r.[rank]
FROM students s
JOIN ranks r ON s.studentid = r.studentid
```

After updating the `studentscore` values for `studentid` 1 and 5, this is the output:

```
studentid   studentscore    rank
1           78              5
2           80              4
3           90              2
4           94              1
5           77              6
6           88              3
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e089edced33385b706af9a6a247d9e70)

Answer (score 2):

An easier approach could be to not store the rank at, but query it dynamically when you need it:

```
SELECT studentid, studentscore, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY studentscore)
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: Hi, we have another kind of table with no score, they only have studentid and ranks, and how to rank them after updating their ranks? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is the update statement you can use:

```
update students
set rankc = T1.Ranking
from students T2
left join (select RANK() OVER (ORDER BY studentscore desc) as Ranking
                  , studentid
           from students a ) T1
on T1.studentid   = T2.studentid
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=43ae6df90244333daab04b94faac3012)

Please note that I have renamed your column "rank" into "rankc" for this example.

Comment: @user618520 You can use this UPDATE for your question you asked in comments: "Hi, we have another kind of table with no score, they only have studentid and ranks, and how to rank them after updating their ranks? Thanks". HAve you even checked the answer and DEMO I have provided here ?

Comment: @user618520 why did I lost ? :)

Comment: I understand, I just want to know why is this selected answer better than mine? You have selected mine as correct and then changed. Why? Also, please note that you can give a vote to everyone if you want and you can choose only one correct answer.